# Необходима помощь с изменением времени при нажатии на кнопку в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

> Прошу увеличите рейтинг данного сообщение на 3. Я осознал свои ошибки, но вопросы еще заблокированы.

Приветствую всех участников! Я столкнулся с ошибкой, которую не могу решить самостоятельно. Пытался реализовать функционал, при котором значение каждой переменной изменялось бы по-разному при нажатии на кнопку в игре **Unity**, с использованием `WaitForSeconds`.

> Хочу предупредить, что у меня ограниченный опыт в программировании, поэтому в моем коде может быть неоптимальное решение с тремя одинаковыми частями для каждой переменной. Попытки самостоятельно исправить ошибки только усложнили ситуацию.

Итак разберем немного мой код.

1. В коде 3 публичных числовых переменных, которые имеют уникальное значение.

```
    public Text sub;
    public int score;

    public Text money;
    public int score1;

    public Text top;
    public int score2;
```

2. В каждой корутине (`CountPoints`, `CountPoints1`, `CountPoints2`) происходит обновление текстовых полей (`sub`, `money`, `top`), а также изменение значений переменных `score`, `score1` и `score2`.

```
   void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints());
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints1());
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints2());
    }
```

3. Проверка условия, пока значение `score` меньше 10000.

```
  while (score < 10000)
```

4. Присваивание текстовому полю `sub` значения `score` как строку и идет увеличение значения переменной `score` на 1, ну а так же приостановка выполнения корутины на 1 секунду.

```
        {
            sub.text = score.ToString();
            score++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
```

5. Ну и аналогичным образом работают и корутины `CountPoints1()` и `CountPoints2()`, но с другими текстовыми полями и переменными, а так с другими значениями `WaitForSeconds`.
6. Я пытался сделать так, чтобы при нажатие кнопки изменялся параметр `WaitForSeconds`, но из за того, что у каждой переменой должен быть уникальное значение `WaitForSeconds`, не смог это сделать...

**Заранее благодарен тем, кто сможет помочь мне разобраться в этих ошибках и указать правильное направление для дальнейшего решения проблемы!**

Вот весь код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text sub;
    public int score;

    public Text money;
    public int score1;

    public Text top;
    public int score2;

    public string product;


    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints());
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints1());
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints2());
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints()
    {
        while (score < 10000)
        {
            sub.text = score.ToString();
            score++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints1()
    {
        while (score1 < 10000)
        {
            money.text = score1.ToString();
            score1++;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CountPoints2()
    {
        while (score2 > 0)
        {
            top.text = score2.ToString();
            score2--;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.6f);
        }
    }

    public void productUpgrade()
    {
        int count = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(product);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(product, count = 1);

        Debug.Log(count + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так понимаю цель в том, что за определённый промежуток времени набрать определённое количество очков? В таком случае я немного переписал код, если у тебя всё же другая задача - напиши, исправлю

Что-ж, первым делом давай создадим новый класс, который будет хранить в себе объект очков определённого типа (новый файл Score.cs):

```cs
using System;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[Serializable]
public class Score
{
    public Text text;
    public int score;

    // Если просто изменять score, то у нас не изменится Text
    // Поэтому добавляем метод для изменения 
    // (P.S.: Рекомендую изучить getter и setter)
    public void SetScore(int score)
    {
        this.score = score;
        text.text = score.ToString();
    }
}
```

Теперь объявим их в Game используя новый тип:

```cs
    public Score sub;
    public Score money;
    public Score top;
```

Напишем каротину для увеличения количества очков на значение `increase` (так же в классе Game)

```cs
    IEnumerator CountPoints(Score scoreObject, int increase)
    {
        // Чем больше количество очков, тем меньше задержа
        // Таким образом очки будут накапливаться всегда за increaseTimeInSeconds секунд
        float delay = 1f / increase * increaseTimeInSeconds; 

        for (var i = 0; i < increase; i++)
        {
            scoreObject.SetScore(scoreObject.score+1); // Добавляем очки
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay); // Ждём
        }
    }
```

Как это используется:

```cs
    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints(sub, 10000)); // Добавляем 10000 очков
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints(money, 10000)); // Добавляем 10000 монет
        StartCoroutine(CountPoints(top, -1000)); // убираем 1000 очков
    }
```

Comment: 'scoreObject.score' никогда не меняется и будет всегда равно 0, т.к. `score` не используется в классе `Score`

Comment: @ExplodingKitten ой, я забыл, 5 секунд

Comment: @ExplodingKitten исправил

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей а через нажатие кнопки, как сделать увеличение скорости работы набора очков?

Comment: @Nymos Не понял. Может вы зададите новый вопрос, где более подробно распишите его?

Comment: @Nymos А, понял, изменяйте increaseTimeInSeconds

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей я пишу новый вопрос

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей Задал новый вопрос!

Comment: потом поставлю обратно галочку, пользователи не хотят смотреть просто мой вопрос

Comment: @Nymos от того что вы сняли галочку списывается с вас 2 репутации и с отвечающего 15 репутации. Больше никакого толку от этого нет.